# saveAs is not a function

Tags: acrobat, pdf-form, acrobat-sdk

I have a button in acrobat form with below script in the Mouse Down.

```
try
{
  app.saveAs("/c/temp/11.pdf");
}
catch(err)
{
  app.alert(err.message);
}
```

when I click on the button I get message box says

app.saveAs is not a function.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want doc.saveAs() See tutorial: https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/how-save-pdf-acrobat-javascript

Comment: thanks for fast reply. how I can get the reference to the document I'm working on? if I use doc.saveAs, I get error: doc is not defined

Comment: The current pdf is returned by `this` so `this.SaveAs()`.

Comment: now I get: security setting prevent access to this property or method. seems I have to use trusted functions???

Comment: Please actually read that tutorial, because there are security settings that may prevent saving. In particular SaveAs will work from the console window as is, but from an actual document script you need to be in the context of a folder-level `trustedFunction` so that you can successfully issue SaveAs.